# Formar una cadena que se forma por un string fijo y uno aleatorio

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Quizás el titulo no este bien explicado porque soy muy novato  pero lo que quiero es esto

```
import random

grupo1=("Niños")
grupo2=("Niñas")
grupo3=("Padres")
grupo4=("Madres")

Resultado=random.randint(0,3)

print (grupo+str(resultado))
```

y si sale en el random un 4 por ejemplo pues que imprima "Madres", se hacerlo de otra forma pero me interesa aprender a unir de esta forma, 
Mil gracias

Comment: No puedes utilizar listas/arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python permite y deja hacer muchas cosas, otra cosa es que sea buena idea hacerlas. Por poder puedes, es más, tienes muchas opciones:

- Usar el diccionario `globals` (o `locals`):

  ```
  print(globals().get(f"grupo{resultado}"))
  ```
- Usar `eval`:

  ```
  print(eval(f"grupo{resultado}"))
  ```
- Usar `getattr`:

  ```
  import sys
  print(getattr(sys.modules[__name__], f"grupo{resultado}", None))
  ```

No obstante, lo adecuado en estos casos es usar un diccionario:

```
import random


grupos = {1: ("Niños"),
          2: ("Niñas"),
          3: ("Padres"),
          4: ("Madres")
          }

resultado = random.randint(1, 4)
print(grupos.get(resultado))
```

Mucho más legible, más escalable, seguro y simple.

O si no son muchas opciones, un bloque condicional sin más:

```
import random


grupo1 = ("Niños")
grupo2 = ("Niñas")
grupo3 = ("Padres")
grupo4 = ("Madres")

resultado = random.randint(1, 4)

if resultado == 1:
    print(grupo1)
elif resultado == 2:
    print(grupo2)
elif resultado == 3:
    print(grupo3)
elif resultado == 4:
    print(grupo4)
```

También en este caso podría usar una simple lista o tupla y `random.choice`:

```
import random


grupos = ["Niños", "Niñas", "Padres", "Madres"]

grupo = random.choice(grupos)
print(grupo)
```

No te complique usando variables, es la peor forma de implementar esto y no hay nada que puedas hacer usando variables individuales y no con un diccionario por ejemplo.

Comment: Nota que en Python no hay diferencia entre `("Niños")` y `"Niños"`: simplemente son cadenas de 5 letras. Pero `("Niños", )` es otro animal: una tupla de un elemento.

Comment: Si, es que copie y pegue el ejemplo del OP sin más XD, en la lista eliminé los paréntesis pero en el diccionario y en los condicionales  se me olvidó... Aún así creo que por el nombre de las variables (grupo) el OP en realidad tiene una tupla o otro contenedor asociado a las variables..